How to break a Vigenère cipher with a partial plaintext and key?
I have an question regarding Vigenère decryption. Is it possible to break a Vigenère with a partial answer key?
Ive got the cipher text: GKFJMNMJLRHLJKSMPFLMYCS
And a partial answer that begins with EEADIHHHJFEFHENGL------
And a partial key that begins with CGFGEGFCCMDGCGFGE
Btw, if you are wondering why the letters are nonsensical, i am trying to unravel a link that is doubly encrypted. The letters will all go into the link from left to right.

Hint: that partial key may contain repetition.
